# Shortcut for automatic execution

Tags: vimrc, external-command, packages

I've found the following command to execute Python or Matlab or any other language as far as I understand to execute code

`nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>`

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948530/1886529))

and

`map <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!%:p<CR>`

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601084/1886529); supposedly should work for all scripts as it uses vim expand however I had this working before but now is giving me a `shell returned 126` error)

Is there a way to automatically execute the code without explicitly specifying the command?

In other words, if I have any script (Matlab, Python, Latex, ...) open and I press `F9` the script is executed?

Or maybe there's a package for such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem had nothing to do with the command listed in the question. **Apparently, the order of the commands in `.vimrc` matters**.

I moved the mapping to the top of the file and it worked.

Hope this helps others while the downvoters continue their greedy search for more points.

Update: It is no longer at the top of the vimrc however at the time it seemed like something else was interfering with it.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `makeprg` option, [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27):

```
                                    *'makeprg'* *'mp'*
'makeprg' 'mp'                      string    (default "make", VMS: "MMS")
                                    global or local to buffer |global-local|
                                    {not in Vi}
    Program to use for the ":make" command.  See :make_makeprg.

    This option may contain '%' and '#' characters, 
    which are expanded to the current and alternate file name.  Use |::S| 
    to escape file names in case they contain special characters.
    Environment variables are expanded |:set_env|.  See |option-backslash|
    about including spaces and backslashes.

    Note that a '|' must be escaped twice: once for ":set" and once for
    the interpretation of a command.  When you use a filter called
    "myfilter" do it like this:

        :set makeprg=gmake\ \\\|\ myfilter

    The placeholder "$*" can be given (even multiple times) to specify
    where the arguments will be included, for example:

        :set makeprg=latex\ \\\\nonstopmode\ \\\\input\\{$*}

    This option cannot be set from a |modeline| or in the |sandbox|, for
    security reasons.
```

The best way to use it is to define the option in an ftplugin. For example for python create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` containing:

```
setlocal makeprg=python\ %
```

Create a new ftplugin and adapt the `makeprg` for each filetype you want to handle.

Then you can simply use the command `:make` in the file you want to source or create a mapping like `nnoremap <F5> :make<CR>`.

Some related help topics:

- [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27)
- [`:h :make`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3amake)
- [`:h ftplugins`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#ftplugins)
- [`:h :setlocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3asetlocal)