# Syntax in autocmd command to compile and run cpp code

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, compile-vim

From this post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540721/compile-directly-from-vim

One of the answer is:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F4> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r <CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap<F5> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r && ./%:r <CR>
```

This works. But I would like to have 2 separate function: one for compile only and the other for run only, instead of compiling and run at the same time.  So I changed it to this:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F4> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r <CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap<F5> : ./%:r <CR>
```

The first command works, it compiles the cpp file whenever I press `F4`.  The second does not work.  The reason, I think is because I am referencing `:r`, which can only be found from the first command.  So, vim does not know what `:r` is.

**Work around**

Of course, the fastest way to fix would be to do:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F4> :!g++ % -ggdb <CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap<F5> : ./a.out <CR>
```

On Linux, without specifying the `-o` flag, `g++` will compile into an `a.out` file, and then I would just run `./a.out`.  This means that every single cpp file would get compiled to `a.out`

However, I would like to retain the file name as part of the executable.  For example, `test.cpp` would compile to `test`...etc.

Is there a way to do this?

**TL,DR**: With the answer from the links given, how can I compile and retain the file name with 1 shortcut, and then on a separate shortcut, run that executable (with the file name retained)?

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone and will expand later on. I very answered this question many times (yes this is a duplicate): we don't need to change makeprg or manually invoke g++ to compile C++ programs from vim. Set $CXXFLAGS and them `:make %<` navigate errors (:h quickffix) and execute with `:!./%<`. Recently I ve given more details on reddit, and I also expand on the subject in an help page of my buildtoolswrapper plugin.

Comment: The help page in question: https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/make_run.md#mono-file-projects

Comment: Thanks @LucHermitte.

Comment: Highly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24561/10604

Comment: And again: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15520/10604

Answer (score 1):

Following instruction here and install appropriate package and set appropriate flags:

https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/make_run.md#mono-file-projects

We can just do `:make %<` and `!./ %<` to build and compile cpp file